# Missing coordinates in raster reprojection from cylindrical equal area to lat/long using Raster function in R

Tags: r, gis, latitude-longitude, raster, projection

I have a raster that I have reprojected from Cylindrical Equal-Area (Lambert) Central Meridian: -160. Datum: WGS 1984 (`+proj=cea +lon_0=Central Meridian +lat_ts=Standard Parallel +x_0=False Easting +y_0=False Northing +ellps=WGS84`) to latitude and longitude.
The original raster looks like this:

```
library(rasterVis)
levelplot(r)
```

[Original raster without missing points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9giay.jpg)

```
r
#class       : RasterLayer 
#dimensions  : 64, 200, 12800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution  : 2e+05, 2e+05  (x, y)
#extent      : -20037507, 19962493, -6363885, 6436115  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=cea +lon_0=-160 +lat_ts=Standard Parallel +x_0=False Easting +y_0=False Northing +ellps=WGS84 
#data source : N:\My documents\Data\Exposure\Reefs at risk\Global_Threats\Acidification\arag_380\w001001.adf
#names       : w001001
#values      : 1.025163, 4.11939  (min, max)
```

I have been able to use the `projectRaster` function from the `Raster` package by cutting the extent of the y-axis of the raster by 0.95 to the North and South. I was having a few problems reprojecting the raster without cutting the extent (see here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220589/error-using-projectraster-in-r-error-in-if-maxy-miny-missing-value-whe/220741#220741).

```
#Cut y-axis values because projectRaster failed using full extent
extent(r) <- c(xmin= -20037507, xmax= 19962493, ymin= 0.95*(-6363885), ymax= 0.95*(6436115))

# Define the new Proj.4 spatial reference 
sr <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

# Project Raster
projected_r <- projectRaster(r, crs = sr, method = 'bilinear')
```

The problem I am having is that there are missing data in the new, reprojected raster.

```
levelplot(projected_r)
```

[reprojected raster with missing points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sXiO.jpg)

The missing coordinates are not located in the 5% North and Souththat I cut from the extent so I am not sure why these data are missing? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I know some colleagues who also faced this problem. I once (spring 2016) showed and asked this problem to one of the chief guys of Google Earth Engine. He replied that they know about it but were not able to figure out the source of the problem. It often occurs when reprojecting this area and since almost all spatial tools rely on the proj4 library, it is most likely related to a bug in this library.